# Toolbar elevation is not at the bottom

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat, android-toolbar, android-elevation

I'm trying to create an extended toolbar, something like:
[image]

My activity xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

From some reason, the elevation is not at the bottom of the Toolbar:
[image]

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it - there are two toolbars displayed, the decor one and the one I've added. Changed my theme to inherit from "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and now only my toolbar is visible.

Thanks anyway!